# odoo days calculation from 9 days only show days then show date

Tags: python, odoo

I have a scenario that in due date only  9 days show days and greater then 9 days show date.
like this pic duedate 8daysago but i want after 9 days write here date 11/2/2022 like something

[image]

Comment: Could you share a sample output?

Comment: I edit my question i hope you can understand

Answer (score 1):

By default `remaining_days` widget display he delta in `days` If the delta is larger than 99 days, otherwise display the date as usual without time.

> Displays the delta (in days) between the value of the field and today.
> If the delta is larger than 99 days, displays the date as usual (without
> time).

You can override [`_renderReadonly()`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L1162) javascript method in web module and change 99 to 9 so if the delta is larger than 9 days the date will be displayed as date.

Override the method and Change the below line

```
if (Math.abs(diffDays) > 99)
```

to

```
if (Math.abs(diffDays) > 9)
```